# Can there be if else loop within if else loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub lol_function()

Dim x, y, count, i, mhr, z, allowed, leftover As Integer

For y = 13 To 210
For x = 6 To 1000 Step 8
allowed = 50 * Cells(x, 8)

mhr = Cells(x, 7)
count = count + mhr

If mhr <= allowed And count <= allowed Then
    Cells(x, y).value = mhr

Else
    Cells(x, y).value = allowed + mhr - count
    y = y + 1

    leftover = count - allowed

If leftover <= allowed Then

    Cells(x, y).value = leftover
    count = leftover

Else

    Cells(x, y).value = allowed
    leftover = mhr - allowed
    y = y + 1

End If

Next x, y

End Sub
```

If I don't use the second if else loop then the code works fine but with second if else statement I keep getting "Next without For" Error. Any help will be appreciated.

Also if I include second end if it messes my code. I need it to be

```
if condition
....

else 
....

       if condition
            .....

       else
            .....

end if
```

Any others way to create loop inside the else statement?

Comment: `Next x, y` is a syntax error (you need 2 closing `Next`'s), and it's missing the `End If` on the line above. [Indenting the code would make this more obvious.](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation)

Comment: Also `Dim x, y, count, i, mhr, z, allowed, leftover As Integer` is not doing what you think it is.  `leftover` is the only variable that is being set as an integer, all the others are `Variants`

Answer (score 4):

Since you have two "If" statements, you need a second "End If" before your "Next" statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the `End If` between the first `Else` and second `If` statements.